# RabbitMQ declare an exchange without a plugin or client

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a use-case where I need to declare Exchanges on RabbitMQ after it is first installed, configured, and started. The properties of the Exchanges (name, type, durable, etc) are located in a file (or files).

This has to be automated and installing the Management Plugin or any other plugin is not an option (not yet).

Is it possible to do this without a client (Java, Erlang, etc)?

I am running CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either installing the management plugin, or using a client are really your only options. Rabbitmqctl is very lightweight, and does not have the ability to create queues nor exchanges. I would suggest getting the management plugin if at all possible. If you have the ability to use something like Python, it has [kombu](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/kombu/) and [pika](https://github.com/pika/pika/), both of which are great clients.

Answer (score 0):

Using python and pika http://pika.github.com/communicating.html, this can be done using only a few lines of code, this can be separate from client program code.

```
def init_broker():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=BROKER_ADDRESS))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.exchange_declare(callback=None, ticket=0, exchange=EXCHANGE, type='direct', passive=False, durable=True, auto_delete=False, internal=False, nowait=False, arguments={})
    channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE, passive=False, durable=True, exclusive=False, auto_delete=False, nowait=False, arguments={})
    channel.queue_bind(callback=None, ticket=0, queue=QUEUE, exchange=EXCHANGE, routing_key=QUEUE, nowait=False, arguments={})
```